# JUnit test passes in Run mode, but fails in debug mode?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, junit, guava

#### Introduction

When I run this test in Run mode

```
@Test
public void testGetFinalOutput() {
    final ObjectLocator dut = new ObjectLocator(ImmutableMap.of(
            TEST_ITEM, new Coordinates(1,1)));

    Assert.assertTrue(dut.getFinalOutput(1, 1).isPresent());
}
```

This will run and passes the assertion.

If I run the same test in Debug mode, I get the following error and stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: (2, 0)=[GameObject{blocking=true, grabbable=false, sprite=ObjectGeometry{foreColor=java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255], backColor=java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0], imgChar=AMPERSAND}, name=test wall, desires=[], detailedDescription=This is a test wall, uuid=6e84f9a5-5039-40a2-acc1-793d50ebded4}] and (2, 0)=[GameObject{blocking=true, grabbable=false, sprite=ObjectGeometry{foreColor=java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255], backColor=java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0], imgChar=AMPERSAND}, name=test wall, desires=[], detailedDescription=This is a test wall, uuid=32ad0809-4252-4883-896a-a3b228c9c250}]
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.conflictException(ImmutableMap.java:211)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.checkNoConflict(ImmutableMap.java:205)
    at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.checkNoConflictInKeyBucket(RegularImmutableMap.java:146)
    at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.fromEntryArray(RegularImmutableMap.java:109)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.build(ImmutableMap.java:390)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSetMultimap.fromMapEntries(ImmutableSetMultimap.java:420)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSetMultimap.copyOf(ImmutableSetMultimap.java:381)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSetMultimap.copyOf(ImmutableSetMultimap.java:363)
    at location.ObjectLocator.mergeValues(ObjectLocator.java:147)
    at location.ObjectLocator.union(ObjectLocator.java:165)
    at location.ObjectLocator.union(ObjectLocator.java:60)
    at generation.BuildingUtils.runWalls(BuildingUtils.java:125)
    at generation.BuildingUtils.buildClosedPolygon(BuildingUtils.java:139)
    at generation.BuildingUtils.buildRectangle(BuildingUtils.java:67)
    at location.ObjectLocatorTest.<clinit>(ObjectLocatorTest.java:39)
    ... 46 more
```

#### Details

The line 39 in ObjectLocatorTest.java which triggers this is part of an initialization of a static field:

```
private static final ObjectLocator VERTICAL = BuildingUtils.buildRectangle(
        TEST_WALL_FACTORY, TEST_FLOOR_FACTORY,
        3,5).translate(1,0);
```

Here's my `mergeValues` in `ObjectLocator.java`:

```
private static <K,V> ImmutableMultimap<K,V> mergeValues(final Multimap<K, V> mapA, final Multimap<K,V> mapB) {
    final Multimap<K,V> retVal = HashMultimap.create();
    for(Map.Entry<K, V> entry : mapA.entries()) {
        retVal.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    for(Map.Entry<K, V> entry : mapB.entries()) {
        retVal.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return ImmutableSetMultimap.copyOf(retVal);
}
```

Where the `return ImmutableSetMultimap.copyOf(retVal);`is on line 147. Shouldn't a Multimap be able to handle "Multiple entries with same key", as the stacktrace complains about?

#### Versions

- I'm running this in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2020.2.
- I'm using guava 30.1-jre
- I'm using Java 8

Comment: Are your entries mutable? Also, why don't you use `ImmutableSetMultimap.<K,V>builder().putAll(mapA).putAll(mapB).build();`

Comment: @Olivier I'm not sure about entries but my keys should be immutable; I'll check every detail in the key class for mutability next chance I can. And originally I had used the builder but I've been trying different things to get the source of the error; I got the same behavior either way.

Comment: It looks like the entries are `Coordinates`. Could you show us that class?

Comment: Also, your stacktrace doesn't show your call to the test. But rather it shows `clinit`. Could you check if your class initialization works? At some point, you must have something like: `static { ... .buildRectangle(); ... }`. That's the part that fails.

Comment: Finally, [IntelliJ allows for breakpoint on exception](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html#exception-breakpoints). Try to find out the content of your maps at that point with your debugger.

Comment: @Olivier I ran the exception breakpoint as you suggested.  I get a bunch of `ClassNotFoundExceptions` related to loading Gradle classes, the first of which is `"worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain"`. Thanks very much for pointing me towards this feature! Unfortunately, I'm still pretty stumped about what is causing this.

Comment: Well, actually, IntelliJ's breakpoint on exception is a bit flawed because it handles *all* exceptions, including those that happen when launching the JVM. Ideally, you should check all the exceptions until the one that happens in your code. Check that `static` block or static field declarations in your `ObjectLocatorTest` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your key class, you overrode Object's `equals(Object obj)` but not `hashCode()`.

Override both properly.

Comment: Whom are you referring to with "you", since you're the OP?

Comment: @Akash me, in the second person.